# Fixar elementos no rodapé da div

Tags: css

Fiz algumas caixas usando listas **< ul>** e **< li>** e gostaria de colocar um título e um "subtítulo" no rodapé, qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso?

Está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Final:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código HTML está assim.

```
<div class="primario">
    <img src="..." title="..." />
    <div class="titulo">
        <h1>Titulo</h1>
        Info
    </div>
</div>
<div class="secundario">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="..." title="..." />
            <div class="titulo">
                <h1>Titulo</h1>
                Info
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="..." title="..." />
            <div class="titulo">
                <h1>Titulo</h1>
                Info
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="..." title="..." />
            <div class="titulo">
                <h1>Titulo</h1>
                Info
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="..." title="..." />
            <div class="titulo">
                <h1>Titulo</h1>
                Info
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Criei uma pequena estrutura para você entender como funciona.

***HTML***

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="footer">
            <h2>Titulo</h2>
            <span>Info</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="footer">
            <h2>Titulo</h2>
            <span>Info</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="footer">
            <h2>Titulo</h2>
            <span>Info</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

***CSS***

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
    margin: 10px;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}

ul li {
    width:220px;
    height:220px;
    background:#999;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
}

ul li div.footer {
    width:100%;
    padding:8px 20px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

ul li div.footer h2 {
    font-size:18px;
    color:#336699;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul li div.footer span {
    display:block;
    color:#e1e1e1;
}
```

Primeiramente defino na `li` a `position:relative` para que eu possa definir depois a `div.footer` a `position:absolute` e `bottom:0` isso fará com que o elemnto fique limitado a `li` e assim chegamos ao resultado desejado.

**[DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/qnxg1jjg/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Tranquilamente você pode fazer isso ai com uma div e um CSS básico. Mas se você estiver querendo produzir mais e com um design bacana e responsivo. Te sugiro dá uma olhada no bootstrap 3.Ando trabalhando bastante com ele.Tem bastante componente pronto e para usa-lós basta acrescentar os scripts no html.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

E aqui estão alguns dos seus componentes http://getbootstrap.com/components/